# Joint probability table converted to a conditional probability table

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

What is being asked of me:

Draw up similar tables defining the conditional probability function of $Y$ given $X = x$, and $X$ given $Y = y$.

Of: This table giving the joint probability function of $X$ and $Y$:
$$\begin{align}
\\ && y=0.5 && y = 1 && y= 1.5
\\x=1 &&\frac{1}{5} && \frac{1}{5} && 0
\\ x=2 &&0&&\frac{3}{10}&&\frac{1}{10}
\\ x=3&&0&&0&&\frac{1}{5}
\end{align}$$

I have made both tables successfully I believe, I would just like to verify, so here is the first one:

$$\begin{align}
\\F_{X|Y} && y=0.5 && y = 1 && y= 1.5
\\x=1 &&1 && \frac{2}{5} && 0
\\ x=2 &&0&&\frac{3}{5}&&\frac{1}{3}
\\ x=3&&0&&0&&\frac{2}{3}
\end{align}$$

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your table for $P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ is correct.

Comment: @StefanHansen
If this layout is at all standard, is it (the layout) correct? Also is $F_{X|Y}$ the correct thing to refer to this as?

Comment: No, $F$ usually refers to the cumulative distribution function. I would use $p_X$ and $p_Y$ to denote the marginal probability functions, i.e. $p_X(x)=P(X=x)$ etc. Then I would use $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$ to denote the joint probability function, i.e. $p_{X,Y}(x,y)=P(X=x,Y=y)$ and $p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$ to denote $P(Y=y\mid X=x)$.

Comment: @StefanHansen was that last one meant to be $p_{Y|X}(x,y)$ and not $p_{Y|X}(y|x)$?

Comment: Also would expected$(Y|X=1)=0.5*\frac{1}{2}+1*\frac{1}{2} + 1.5*0=.75$?

Comment: No, it was intentional to write $p_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x)$. This is just notation, and hence you could in principle write it however you want. But this is the notation I've seen used frequently. For the conditional expectation, I wouldn't know since I haven't seen the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.